# Twisted Names - Authoritative Server - More than one zone

Tags: python, dns, twisted

I'll try to create an authoritative server with twisted names. According to the docs i can define a zone file like this:

```
twistd -n dns --pyzone example-domain.com
```

But... how can I specify more than one zone file?

```
twistd -n dns --pyzone example-domain.com example-domain.net
```

or

```
twistd -n dns --pyzone example-domain.com --pyzone example-domain.net
```

wont work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you say this won't work?

```
twistd -n dns --pyzone example-domain.com --pyzone example-domain.net
```

I run a server just like that, serving about a dozen different zones.